# C# Error with random number generator. "Error code : CS1061. Doesn't contain a definition for 'Next'"

Tags: c#, random, int

My number guessing game random number generator doesn't work correctly.

Script : [here](https://gist.github.com/Vlatkoski/694796a430084f0f1b8bc888233be5fa)

> Error:
>
> > Assets/Script/NumberWizard.cs(23,24): error CS1061: Type 'UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and no extension method 'Next' of type 'UnityEngine.Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Expected:
>
> > Return a random value between 0 & 1000.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take the [tour], and please learn how to [ask] with a [mcve]. Please do not post screenshots of your code or error messages. Read this: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245) and [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: you are using untity.random - here is its man page https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html. I suspect you want system.random, you will have to explicity say system.random

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the wrong [Random](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) from Unity instead of [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to use System.Random(), but you are using UnityEngine.Random(). add using System and use System.Random() instead of Random().